# Scrapy Link Extractor Only Retrieves Subset of Listings

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to open all links of property listings on pages 1- 617 of this base page: "https://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/verkocht/sorteer-afmelddatum-af".

When reviewing my results I expected to see a dataset including all listed properties but noticed that Scrapy only scraped some listings but skips others (Example: "Eef Kamerbeekstraat 504 + PP" on page 209 is skipped. Please find below the script of my scraper (note: I am using Scrapy 2.6.2.)

I am interested in knowing why my scraper skips listings and what I can do to fix this.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class FundaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'funda_verkocht'
    allowed_domains = ['funda.nl']
    start_urls = []
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/verkocht/sorteer-afmelddatum-af/', headers={
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent
        })


    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@data-object-url-tracking='resultlist']"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@rel='next']"), follow = True)
    )

    def set_user_agent(self, request):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        return request

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield{
            'address': response.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@class='object-header__title']/text())").get(),
            'postal_code': response.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@class='object-header__subtitle fd-color-dark-3']/text())").get(),
            'offered_since': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Aangeboden sinds']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'asking-price': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div/strong[@class='object-header__price--historic']/text())").get(),
            'surface': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Wonen']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span/text())").get(),
            'energy_label': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Energielabel']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'housing_type': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Soort appartement']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'build_year': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Bouwjaar']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'number_rooms': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Aantal kamers']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'number_bathrooms': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Aantal badkamers']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'bathroom_facilities': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Badkamervoorzieningen']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'total_floors': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Aantal woonlagen']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'isolation': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Isolatie']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'heating': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Verwarming']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'warm_water': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Warm water']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'cv_ketel': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Cv-ketel']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'land_ownership': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Eigendomssituatie']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'erfpacht': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Lasten']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'location': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Ligging']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'balcony_terrace': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Balkon/dakterras']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'parking': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Soort parkeergelegenheid']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'garden': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Tuin']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'inhabitants_neighborhood': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[.='Inwoners']/following-sibling::div[1]//text())").get(),
            'families_with_kids_perc': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[.='Gezin met kinderen']/following-sibling::div[1]//text())").get(),
            'neighborhood_price_sqm': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[.='Gem. vraagprijs / m²']/following-sibling::div[1]//text())").get()

        }
```

Comment: for me "Eef Kamarbeekstraat 504 +PP" is on page 211 and it extracted fine for me.  Both the input and output are asynchronous for scrapy so items will not always be processed and output in the same order they were input... you might get an item on page 59 next to one from page 12....

Comment: I got the same results as @Alexander. Everything is fine with the code.

Comment: Hey both, thank you for your feedback! I just checked my dataset and realized that my spider successfully scrapes the first 50 pages and after these access to funda.nl is refused. I assume this happens because of my setting file. Could you share how you have set up your setting.py file?