# Scrapy Link Extractor Only Retrieves Subset of Listings

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to open all links of property listings on pages 1- 617 of this base page: "https://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/verkocht/sorteer-afmelddatum-af".

When reviewing my results I expected to see a dataset including all listed properties but noticed that Scrapy only scrapes content from the first 100 pages and skips the rest (Example: "Eef Kamerbeekstraat 504 + PP" on page 209 is skipped. Since my spider seems to work as expected for other users (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74600306/scrapy-link-extractor-only-retrieves-subset-of-listings?noredirect=1#comment131703789_74600306)) I assume that I am experiencing issues due to my settings.

Please find below the script of my scraper and setting file below (note: I am using Scrapy 2.6.2.)

My scraper

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class FundaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'funda_verkocht'
    allowed_domains = ['funda.nl']
    start_urls = []
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/verkocht/sorteer-afmelddatum-af/', headers={
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent
        })


    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@data-object-url-tracking='resultlist']"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@rel='next']"), follow = True)
    )

    def set_user_agent(self, request):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        return request

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield{
            'address': response.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@class='object-header__title']/text())").get(),
            'postal_code': response.xpath("normalize-space(//span[@class='object-header__subtitle fd-color-dark-3']/text())").get(),
            'offered_since': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Aangeboden sinds']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'asking-price': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div/strong[@class='object-header__price--historic']/text())").get(),
            'surface': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Wonen']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span/text())").get(),
            'energy_label': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Energielabel']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'housing_type': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Soort appartement']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'build_year': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Bouwjaar']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'number_rooms': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Aantal kamers']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'number_bathrooms': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Aantal badkamers']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'bathroom_facilities': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Badkamervoorzieningen']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'total_floors': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Aantal woonlagen']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'isolation': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Isolatie']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'heating': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Verwarming']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'warm_water': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Warm water']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'cv_ketel': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Cv-ketel']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'land_ownership': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Eigendomssituatie']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'erfpacht': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Lasten']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'location': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Ligging']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'balcony_terrace': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Balkon/dakterras']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'parking': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Soort parkeergelegenheid']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'garden': response.xpath("normalize-space(//dt[.='Tuin']/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text())").get(),
            'inhabitants_neighborhood': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[.='Inwoners']/following-sibling::div[1]//text())").get(),
            'families_with_kids_perc': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[.='Gezin met kinderen']/following-sibling::div[1]//text())").get(),
            'neighborhood_price_sqm': response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[.='Gem. vraagprijs / m²']/following-sibling::div[1]//text())").get()

        }
```

My settings

```
# Scrapy settings for funda project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'funda'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['funda.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'funda.spiders'
#USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.7'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'funda (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Comment: A better diagnostic tool would be to copy the log output scrapy creates into a file and upload it to a pastebin and copy the link here.  there is nothing wrong with your settings.

Comment: Hey @Alexander, thank you for your help. The scrapy output seems to be too large for pastebin so I uploaded it to github: https://github.com/LisaHer/TMP/blob/main/funda_scraper_output.txt. According to this output scrapy successfully scraped 1205 listings but the page has in total more than 9000 listings. Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: try experimenting with the [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) and [DOWNLOAD_DELAY](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) and see if there is some combination that will allow you to extract more pages than you have so far.

Comment: I m agree with Alexander. Try Autothrotling on in your project settings then run the spider.

Comment: @Alexander - I just set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS =2 and it worked: my scraper scraped all 9187 listings! Thanks a lot! Do you want to post your above comment as the answer so I can select it as the correct answer? :)

Comment: @Bashar - thanks a lot for your help. The adjustment in the settings helped indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your logs it appears that there are limitations on your side of the network connection.

Try experimenting with the `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` and `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and see if that fixes the problem or if there is some combination that will allow you to extract more pages than you have so far.

[`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests)

[`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay)